# C#: how to use Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles

Tags: c#, compact-framework, namespaces

Why does 
`using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles`
cause the C# Compiler Error:

> The type or namespace name
>   'SafeHandles' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.Win32'

This code is lifted from http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/serialport-ioexception-workaround-in-c.html

Comment: It works just fine in a brand new WinForms and WPF project. What are you using instead?

Comment: What Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: I've added it to an existing WinForms project.

Comment: Is this project targeting at least version 2.0 of the .NET Framework? There's nothing I can find to do to a WinForms project that breaks that namespace...

Comment: I am targeting Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE. v3.5 does not run on my target which is Windows CE 5.0

Comment: And *there's* the clue we needed! Glad we could resolve this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use sample code written for the normal .Net Framework in a Compact Framework project. This class is not supported by the CF.

Comment: @JackN: You should be able to just use an `IntPtr` under the Compact Framework. Is there a specific reason why you need the `SafeHandle` class?

Comment: No reason why I need SafeHandle. I was using zachsaws code. I'll use IntPtr instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a SafeHandle in the Compact Framework, the SDF [does include one](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d0d5f3ff-6f72-deb4-6b57-158d8dfddce3.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There's no SafeHandles in CF. Check out [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/)